# How do you get Legendaries back?

Tags: pokemon-omega-ruby-alpha-sapphire

I sold off my Lugia, Heatran, and Regigigas to get Mewtwo, Palkia and Porygon. I want to get them back without trading. Can I get them back by beating the Elite Four again?

Comment: When you say "Sold Off," do you mean traded away?

Comment: @ShadowZ. So it seems, he got 3 other Pokemon for them.

Comment: Depends. Are you willing to erase your save and start a new game?

Answer (score 4):

No, if you have already caught them previously. They can re-appear only if you defeat them.